SonarQube integration with Azure DevOps fails
I'm using community edition of SonarQube on my Ubuntu machine and self-hosted agent in Azure DevOps.
I tried to integrate SonarQube in the pipeline using 2 different codes but none seems to be working.
1st pipeline
steps:
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    extraProperties: |
      # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner,
      # Put one key=value per line, example:
      # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
      sonar.projectKey=my_sonar_project_key
      sonar.projectName=my_project_name

- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/17.0.10+7/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.10+7-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK17

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_17/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false


- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_17_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '5.0.0.4638'
    spotBugsAnalysis: false
    
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

but this is the error that I receive

##[warning]No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration.

2nd pipeline
steps:
- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/17.0.10+7/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.10+7-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK17

- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  displayName: Prepare SonarQube
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'file'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.projectKey= my_sonar_project_key
      sonar.projectName=$(SONAR_PREFIX_KEY)-$(app-name):$(app-name)
      sonar.branch.name='$(SonarBranchName)'
      sonar.host.url= my_sonar_url
      sonar.login= my_sonar_token

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_17/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false

- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_17_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '5.0.0.4638'
    spotBugsAnalysis: false


- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
  condition: always()
  displayName: Run SonarQube analysis

- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  displayName: 'Publish SonarQube analysis'
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

- task: sonar-buildbreaker@8
  condition: and(succeeded(),eq(variables.ableToScan, 'true'))
  displayName: "Evaluate SonarQube results"
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'


I end up by receiving


warning : This task was configured to use Java 11, but the SonarQube server v10.5.0 does not support it. Ignoring the configuration and using JAVA_HOME instead. Specify jdkversion in your task definition to use Java 17 to remove this warning.**
error : Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.


Although I have verified the permissions and the token from SonarQube and added my credentials in sonarqube.properties. But, the one created by Gradle only contains  Default SonarQube server and Default source code encoding

For your 1st pipeline, I noticed you asked this similar question yesterday and found that your Gradle@3 task is failed. I believe this failed test resulted in the files required by SonarQube not being generated. You need to fix the error and make the build success.
For your 2nd pipeline, in Azure DevOps integration document of SonarQube, it mentions Run code analysis task is Not used in Maven or Gradle projects. So this task is not needed. And it provides the Steps to construct your Azure pipeline for Gradle, which using scannerMode: 'Other' and this is the same as your  1st pipeline.

From my understanding, I'll be using the first one. but the problem is that I'm not responsible for the code of the application, I'm only asked to create a pipeline for it and it always fails due to the failure of the task Gradle@3.  It is for my school project and i'm working on ElementX android application which is a public repository.@miao-tian-msft

Also I have asked you but i don't know if it is permissible on this platform if there is someway to contact you directly to talk about this issue @miao-tian-msft
